# Why won't python print this string? It returns fine

Tags: python, string

Python won't print this formatted string. It gripes about a syntax error immediately after the second quote. On the other hand, when I return the same string, it does just fine. I'm probably being dumb, but what's the issue here?

```
print '{0} lands by turn {1}: {2}'.format(lands, turn, land_drop_prob(lands, turn, lands=lands_in_deck, deck_size = 60))
```

As mentioned before, if I change "print" to "return", the string returns just fine.

Comment: What version of Python are you using? In Python 3, you have to put parens around the argument to `print` because it's a function.

Comment: Oh geez. That's what it is. I'm not on my regular system.

Comment: Whenever you move to a new platform, always check if you're using Py2 or Py3 because Py3 is intentionally backwards incompatible and has a lot of changes in it.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about a user error (too localized)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your syntax should works with python 2.X. However, with python 3.X, `print` syntax has changed. You have to write `print("blabla")` instead of `print "blabla"`.

```
>>> print '{0} lands by turn {1}: {2}'.format("a", "b", "c")
  File "<stdin>", line 1
    print '{0} lands by turn {1}: {2}'.format("a", "b", "c")
                                     ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
>>> print('{0} lands by turn {1}: {2}'.format("a", "b", "c"))
a lands by turn b: c
>>>
```